# Android zoom image from thumb to center

Tags: android, image, zooming

I am following the following tutorial to zoom an image from thumb in Android http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html

Everything works great except that I would like the zoomed image to be centered in the view and have a maximum size (not fill_parent or match_parent as in the tutorial). I have identical code but my XML is different to try to center the image, but It does not work. What is the problem?

```
<FrameLayout.....
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/te"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/memory_expanded_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxHeight="150dp"
        android:maxWidth="150dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_zoom_touch_close" />

</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Part of the zoom code (identical to tutorial). I think I need to change something here, the finalBounds but I could not figure it out.

```
// Calculate the starting and ending bounds for the zoomed-in image.
// This step involves lots of math. Yay, math.
final Rect startBounds = new Rect();
final Rect finalBounds = new Rect();
final Point globalOffset = new Point();

// The start bounds are the global visible rectangle of the thumbnail,
// and the final bounds are the global visible rectangle of the container
// view. Also set the container view's offset as the origin for the
// bounds, since that's the origin for the positioning animation
// properties (X, Y).
thumbView.getGlobalVisibleRect(startBounds);
findViewById(R.id.container)
        .getGlobalVisibleRect(finalBounds, globalOffset);
startBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);
finalBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify the `finalBounds` to match the actual size of the image. Something like this

```
int imageHeight = expandedImageView.getHeight();
int imageWidth = expandedImageView.getWidth();
int horizontalMargin = 0,  verticalMargin = 0;
if (imageHeight < finalBounds.height()) {
    verticalMargin = (finalBounds.height() / 2) - (imageHeight / 2);
}
if (imageWidth < finalBounds.width()) {
    horizontalMargin = (finalBounds.width() / 2) - (imageWidth / 2);
}
finalBounds.set(finalBounds.left + horizontalMargin, finalBounds.top + verticalMargin, finalBounds.right - horizontalMargin, finalBounds.bottom - verticalMargin);
```

**Full code:**

Layout:

```
<Framelayout
...
...
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/memory_expanded_image"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:contentDescription="@string/description_zoom_touch_close"
   android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

Activity:

```
private void zoomImageFromThumb(final View thumbView, int imageResId) {
        // If there's an animation in progress, cancel it immediately and proceed with this one.
        if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
            mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
        }

        // Load the high-resolution "zoomed-in" image.
        final ImageView expandedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.memory_expanded_image);
        expandedImageView.setImageResource(imageResId);

        // Calculate the starting and ending bounds for the zoomed-in image. This step
        // involves lots of math. Yay, math.
        final Rect startBounds = new Rect();
        final Rect finalBounds = new Rect();
        final Point globalOffset = new Point();

        // The start bounds are the global visible rectangle of the thumbnail, and the
        // final bounds are the global visible rectangle of the container view. Also
        // set the container view's offset as the origin for the bounds, since that's
        // the origin for the positioning animation properties (X, Y).
        thumbView.getGlobalVisibleRect(startBounds);
        findViewById(R.id.container).getGlobalVisibleRect(finalBounds, globalOffset);
        startBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);
        finalBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);

        //modify the final rect to match actual size of the image
        int imageHeight = expandedImageView.getHeight();
        int imageWidth = expandedImageView.getWidth();
        int horizontalMargin = 0,  verticalMargin = 0;
        if (imageHeight < finalBounds.height()) {
            verticalMargin = (finalBounds.height() / 2) - (imageHeight / 2);
        }
        if (imageWidth < finalBounds.width()) {
            horizontalMargin = (finalBounds.width() / 2) - (imageWidth / 2);
        }
        finalBounds.set(finalBounds.left + horizontalMargin, finalBounds.top + verticalMargin, finalBounds.right - horizontalMargin, finalBounds.bottom - verticalMargin);


        // Adjust the start bounds to be the same aspect ratio as the final bounds using the
        // "center crop" technique. This prevents undesirable stretching during the animation.
        // Also calculate the start scaling factor (the end scaling factor is always 1.0).
        float startScale;
        if ((float) finalBounds.width() / finalBounds.height()
                > (float) startBounds.width() / startBounds.height()) {
            // Extend start bounds horizontally
            startScale = (float) startBounds.height() / finalBounds.height();
            float startWidth = startScale * finalBounds.width();
            float deltaWidth = (startWidth - startBounds.width()) / 2;
            startBounds.left -= deltaWidth;
            startBounds.right += deltaWidth;
        } else {
            // Extend start bounds vertically
            startScale = (float) startBounds.width() / finalBounds.width();
            float startHeight = startScale * finalBounds.height();
            float deltaHeight = (startHeight - startBounds.height()) / 2;
            startBounds.top -= deltaHeight;
            startBounds.bottom += deltaHeight;
        }

        // Hide the thumbnail and show the zoomed-in view. When the animation begins,
        // it will position the zoomed-in view in the place of the thumbnail.
        thumbView.setAlpha(0f);
        expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // Set the pivot point for SCALE_X and SCALE_Y transformations to the top-left corner of
        // the zoomed-in view (the default is the center of the view).
        expandedImageView.setPivotX(0f);
        expandedImageView.setPivotY(0f);

        // Construct and run the parallel animation of the four translation and scale properties
        // (X, Y, SCALE_X, and SCALE_Y).
        AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
        set
                .play(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X, startBounds.left,
                        finalBounds.left))
                .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.Y, startBounds.top,
                        finalBounds.top))
                .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_X, startScale, 1f))
                .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_Y, startScale, 1f));
        set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
        set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mCurrentAnimator = null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                mCurrentAnimator = null;
            }
        });
        set.start();
        mCurrentAnimator = set;

        // Upon clicking the zoomed-in image, it should zoom back down to the original bounds
        // and show the thumbnail instead of the expanded image.
        final float startScaleFinal = startScale;
        expandedImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
                    mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
                }

                // Animate the four positioning/sizing properties in parallel, back to their
                // original values.
                AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
                set
                        .play(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X, startBounds.left))
                        .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.Y, startBounds.top))
                        .with(ObjectAnimator
                                .ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_X, startScaleFinal))
                        .with(ObjectAnimator
                                .ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_Y, startScaleFinal));
                set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
                set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
                set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
                        expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mCurrentAnimator = null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                        thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
                        expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mCurrentAnimator = null;
                    }
                });
                set.start();
                mCurrentAnimator = set;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I tried out this code (modification of final bounds). Now the zoomed image  is not in the upper right corner (as was also in OP case), but not in the center of the view either. It is below and to the right of the center of the container view

Comment: Did you change the xml also? Please check in answer.

Comment: Can you please point out, what is important in this XML? Is it "wrap content", because I have layout_width and layout_height set id dp, could this be a problem?

Comment: yes..`layout_width` and `layout_height` should be wrap_content.

Comment: And remove maxHeight, maxwidth, adjustViewBounds, layout_centerInParent, gravity, scaleType properties

Comment: Oh:( ... if I have to remove these properties it will quite dramatically change my layout. (I defined the size of image by layout_width and layout_height for different screen sizes by setting apropriate dimension id dp, note I'm using SVG images as source). Nevermind, if there won't be any other answer I will reward yours.

Comment: That's fine. But I'm sure even if you are setting the dimension programmatically, we can still fix this issue. If possible, post the code snippet where you are setting the size of the image. or else it would be difficult to find out the exact issue :)

Comment: I'm not setting the image size programatically, but in layout.xml e.g. for sw480dp  >             android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"   for sw600dp  I have another layout.xml and so on

Comment: Okay. And the image size is fixed? You won't be changing the image size as you change the image resource?

Comment: Yes,image size is fixed

Comment: Then it's easy fix I guess. Check my edited answer. No need to change anything in xml.